# "That there are more galaxies in the universe."

Tags: meaning-in-context, reading-comprehension, discourse-context

Consider the Q&A in this photo:

[image]

What does the speaker mean by "That there are more galaxies in the universe."? Does he mean that even though Kajol is the best actress in the universe, the others are exceptional actresses in their own right?

Answer (score 1):

Logically it doesn't make much sense.  It seems to be similar to expressions like "there are more fish in the sea", and so is a reminder that there are alternatives.

He's probably saying that Juhi etc are would best actresses in their own galaxy, and so they are exceptional actresses too. Don't try to analyse this too much.

Comment: thank you for the response